# Make an array equal to another array for specific objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview

What I'm trying to do is to make an array equal to another but for specific objects. Like the second array holds a lot of objects and I want the first array to take specific objects from the second array and then return it in NumberOfRowsInSection.

Here is what I tried but it returns nothing:

```
-(NSInteger) tableView: (UITableView * ) tableView numberOfRowsInSection: (NSINteger) section {

     NSArray *array;
    NSString * foundString;
    NSInteger i;
    for (i = 0; i < [LabelFilesArray count]; i++) {
        if ([[[LabelFilesArray objectAtIndex: i] objectForKey: @"teamSide"] isEqualToString: @"test2"]) {
            array = [LabelFilesArray objectAtIndex: i] ObjectForKey: @"teamSide"]; //Here is my problem.
            foundString = @"found";
            if ([foundString isEqualToString: @"found"]) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return array.count; //it returns nothing
}
```

Comment: Can you format your code and fix indentation issues?

Comment: Show examples of the input data and what you want out and what you get

Comment: What do you mean?  my code runs perfectly but the array part is what im having troubles with

Comment: @ozgur That comment is not really constructive. As Malcolm seems to be new on StackOverflow you could have done that for him and refer him to: http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking We all need to help each other.

Comment: Where (and how) have you defined `array`?

Comment: the LabelFilesArray  takes data from a parse.com query that i have in this class and it holds alot of strings and i want  array to take all the identical strings from the LabelFilesArray and hold it.

Comment: So you want to filter `LabelFilesArray` to include only those in this other array?  Start by creating a 3rd array; this will be your "rendering array" (the array which represents the tableview).  You don't want to be doing complex calculations in your datasource methods.

Comment: yea thats what i meant sorry. i want to filter LabelFilesArray

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep things simple, so select the data you want in your tableview as soon as you get it, and store it in a 3rd array.

This allows you to delete and re-arrange rows and makes your datasource methods simple.

ViewController.m:

```
@interface ViewController()
{
    NSMutableArray *_tableData;
}

- (void)methodThatGetsData
{
   // Get data in LabelFilesArray

    _tableData = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (NSDictionary *dict in LabelFilesArray) {
        for (NSString *filter in _filterArray) {
            if (dict[@"teamSide"] isEqualToString:filter]) {
                [_tableData addObject:dict];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    [_tableView reloadData];
}

-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection: (NSINteger)section {
    [_tableData count];
}

// etc.
```

Comment: yes please. what i meant was is to filter LabelFilesArray and then return the filtered array

Comment: @malcolm OK, updated.  I've assumed this array contains dictionaries.  Also that `_filterArray` contains the array of filter strings.

Comment: @malcolm If this answer solved your problem you should indicate this by accepting the answer (click the checkmark).

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSPredicate also to filter contents of array.

**Example:**

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K = %@", key, [dict objectForKey:key]];
_filterArray = [LabelFilesArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```